# Laravel foreach last element move to first

Tags: laravel, foreach

I'm trying to build simple CMS in laravel 5. And here's my problem:

[image]

I wan't to move that Test | New Topic to **first page, first value**. Because I have `is_new_topic` row in PhpMyAdmin. So I wan't to check is post is `is_new_topic == 1` then move it to first foreach value.

`viewTopic` controller:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use View;

class viewTopic extends Controller 
{
    public function showTopic($tname, $tid)
    {
        $topics  = DB::table('topics')
                    ->where('id', $tid)
                    ->where('seo_title', $tname)
                    ->first();

        $posts  = DB::table('posts')
                    ->where('topic_id', $tid)
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.author_id')
                    ->select()
                    ->paginate(3);

        return View::make('posts', compact('topics', 'posts'));
    }
}
```

Route:

`Route::get('topic/{tname}/{tid}', 'viewTopic@showTopic');`

Template:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('breadcrumb')
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="active" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ $topics->title }}">{{ $topics->title }}</li>
</ol>
@stop
@section('content')
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-body" rel="#author{{ $topics->author_id }}">
  </div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="{{ generateProfileURL(str_slug($post->name), $post->id) }}">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://localhost/uploads/avatars/{{ $post->avatar_id }}.{{ $post->avatar_end }}" style="width: 64px">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body" rel="#post{{ $post->pid }}">
  <a href="{{ generateProfileURL($post->name, $post->id) }}">{{ $post->name }}</a><br>{{ $post->text }}
  @if (Auth::check())
  @if($post->id == Auth::user()->id)
  <br><a href="#">Edit</a>
  @endif
  @endif
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
{!! $posts->render() !!}
@stop
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to `order by is_new_topic DESC` ?

Comment: @AlexTartan IDK i'm newbie, how to do it?

Comment: In general it would be a better idea to sort by creation date. It's less work and you don't need to care about it when doing further changes (e.g. what happens when the newest comment is deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing that the values in `is_new_topic` column are 1 for new and 0 for old. You'll have to orderby by that column `desc` like in the  code below:

```
$posts  = DB::table('posts')
                    ->where('topic_id', $tid)
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.author_id')
                    ->orderBy('is_new_topic', 'desc');
                    ->select()
                    ->paginate(3);
```